# haproxy require client certificate for specific url?

Tags: certificate, client, haproxy

I want to configure Haproxy so that it only requires client certificate when specific URL accessed?  Ex:

www.test.com     - it proceeds normally.
www.test.com/secure   - haproxy requires the client certificate.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

To understand why this isn't directly possible requires an understanding of how TLS (SSL) works.  TLS encrypts the connection *before* the HTTP request is sent (over the now-encrypted connection).  By the time the URL is known by HAProxy, the time for requiring a client certificate has already passed.

For practical reasons, an endpoint (HAProxy `frontend` or `listen`) needs to either require a certificate for connections, or not... however, using [`verify optional`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.1-verify) it *might* be possible to achieve what you want.  Using `verify optional` means that the proxy will ask for a client cert upon connection, and if *either* the client offers no cert *or* if the cert is valid according to the `ca-file`, the client will be allowed to connect.  Invalid certs will result in disconnection.

Then, the [`ssl_c_used` fetch](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#ssl_c_used) could be used to deny requests for that path for clients who didn't present the "optional" certificate, earlier.

```
http-request deny if { path_beg /secure } ! { ssl_c_used }
```

The viability of this solution depends on how gracefully browsers behave when asked for a certificate that they would not have -- and all connecting browsers will be asked for a certificate.

But there is no way of doing *exactly* what you are asking, either in HAProxy or on any other platform since, by design, the path is unknown until after TLS negotiation is already complete.

Comment: Another possible option is to emulate what Tomcat does... It will renegotiate SSL after the GET request. I'm not sure if this is possible in haproxy.

Comment: I have tomcat only request certs on requests to /api/v1/ -- Would love to be able to do this with haproxy. Here's what Tomcat's update looks like from curl: https://pastebin.com/raw/jYNcTqXu